# Opening Another Application From My App

Tags: facebook, uiwebview, ios7.1

this is my first question on the site so if i don't cover anything please let me know and i'll try and fix it :P

I'm trying to make my application load another app from inside the app. An example which i can use to make what I'm trying to do more clear is, I want to load FaceBook from my application without it loading a UIWebView. I would like to do this for Facebook, YouTube, Twitter & Instagram. Also if possible all going to specific areas on the site, so the Facebook profile, YouTube channel, Twitter Page & Instagram profile!

Also I know i would have to write an if statement for it to be, if the user has set application on their device then load in that application else if they don't then load in the web view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) of the other apps.  If you know the URL scheme of an app then you can use [openUrl:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL%3a) to send a message to another application and bring it to the foreground.

After a quick search you can find some popular app url schemes [here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) along with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URL Schemes, this wiki has the major ones listed

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes